# How to add a month to a datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to use quarterly variables that are aligned to first quarter, fourth quarter, seventh quarter and so forth. Using business quarters and trying to add one working month to them

```
start = datetime.date.today()
start=start+pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)
end = datetime.date(start.year+2, 12, 31)
business_days_rng =pd.date_range(start, end, freq='BQ')
```

but I get a message saying:

> Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: It works fine with pandas `1.2.3`.

Comment: maybe you should use `pandas.Timestamp` instead of `datetime` - similar to examples in documentation for [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)

Comment: which line makes problem? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  time delta

```
datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)
```

but for longer periods  relative delta will be convenient

This uses the python-dateutil extension

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

six_months = date.today() + relativedelta(months=+6)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it takes care of issues with 28, 30, 31 days etc. This becomes very useful in handling business rules and scenarios (say invoice generation etc.)

```
$ date(2010,12,31)+relativedelta(months=+1)
  datetime.date(2011, 1, 31)

$ date(2010,12,31)+relativedelta(months=+2)
  datetime.date(2011, 2, 28)
```